# Asymptotics of linear combination

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Suppose to have a sequence of bases $\{ v_1(N), \ldots, v_d(N) \}_{N \in \mathbb{N}}$ in a $d$-dimensional vector space, i.e. for each $N$ these vectors give a basis. Moreover, every limit $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} v_i(N)$ exists and is finite and not the zero vector.

Now let $v$ be a vector independent of $N$. We express $v$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors:
$$v = \sum_i a_i(N) v_i(N) $$

Now if I take (entry-wise) asymptotic vectors $v'_i(N) \sim v_i(N)$ such that $v'_i$ still form a basis, and take
$$v = \sum_i a_i'(N) v_i'(N)$$

Can I conclude that $a_i(N) \sim a'_i(N)$?

Comment: I think a counterexample may arise if $v_i(N) \to L$ and $v_j(N) \to L$ for some $i \ne j$.

Comment: What is an "(entry-wise) asymptotic vector"?